# Apache async HttpClient not fast

Tags: java, apache, apache-httpclient-4.x, asynchttpclient

I am pretty new to Apache http client and am trying to get status code from a website. Found the following example on Apache http tutorial.

```
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.config.RequestConfig;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.concurrent.FutureCallback;
import org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.CloseableHttpAsyncClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.HttpAsyncClients;
public class Abc {
    static long d2;
    public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
        d2=System.currentTimeMillis();
        RequestConfig requestConfig = RequestConfig.custom()
            .setSocketTimeout(3000)
            .setConnectTimeout(3000).build();
        CloseableHttpAsyncClient httpclient = HttpAsyncClients.custom()
            .setDefaultRequestConfig(requestConfig)
            .build();
        try {
            httpclient.start();
            final HttpGet[] requests = new HttpGet[] {
                    new HttpGet("http://192.168.26.175:8080/examples/eye/abc10000.jsp")
            };
            final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
            for (int v=0;v<1000;v++) {
                httpclient.execute(requests[0], new FutureCallback<HttpResponse>() {

                    public void completed(final HttpResponse response) {
                        latch.countDown();
                        System.out.println(requests[0].getRequestLine() + "->" + response.getStatusLine());
                    }

                    public void failed(final Exception ex) {
                        latch.countDown();
                        System.out.println(requests[0].getRequestLine() + "->" + ex);
                    }

                    public void cancelled() {
                        latch.countDown();
                        System.out.println(requests[0].getRequestLine() + " cancelled");
                    }

                });
            }
            latch.await();
            System.out.println("Shutting down");
        } finally {
            httpclient.close();
        }
        System.out.println("Done");
      long  d1=System.currentTimeMillis();
      System.out.println(d1-d2);
    }

}
```

Is it really asynchronous or are the calls made serially. What has to be done to make calls asynchronous and faster.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As the requests are going through the same route following changes will have to be made.

```
CloseableHttpAsyncClient httpclient = HttpAsyncClients.custom()
            .setDefaultRequestConfig(requestConfig)
            .setMaxConnPerRoute(1000)
            .setMaxConnTotal(1000)
            .build();
```

Comment: why 1000 ? is there a way to recycle the 'httpclient'  ?

Answer (score 6):

First and foremost: `CloseableHttpAsyncClient` instances are very expensive. Please do **NOT** create a new `CloseableHttpAsyncClient` for each and every request. It is like creating a new browser process for each link click, is completely wasteful and is very slow. It is strongly recommended to use the same `CloseableHttpAsyncClient` instance for the entire lifespan of a logical component.

Pretty much in all cases a blocking client is likely to be considerably faster than a non-blocking (NIO based) one (as long as the number of concurrent requests is below, say, 1000). Unless you are building a proxy of some sort you might be much better served by a blocking HTTP client such as Apache HttpClient.

Comment: I actually want all the requests to be done asynchronous  but what it is doing is that making them serially.

Comment: Naturally, if you keep on creating new client instances for each request, you will be executing only one request at a time

Comment: I guess the client instance has been made only once. Could you please guide me through

Comment: I figured it out. Had to set `setMaxConnPerRoute(500)` as all the requests went through the same route. Thanks bdw!